# When i send to present MKAnnotationView to detail view controller app crashed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i want send annotation info to detail view controller through segue, but when i tapped app crashed and show log *-[UINavigationController setAnnotation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b367870'* 
i use this code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view   calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"presentDetailViewController" sender:view];
} 
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"presentDetailViewController"]) {
         MKAnnotationView *annotationView = sender;
         [[segue destinationViewController] setAnnotation:annotationView.annotation];
    }
}
```

and detail view controller:

```
@interface ACDetailMapController : UIViewController

-(void)setAnnotation:(ACAnnotations *)annotation;
@end

-(void)setAnnotation:(ACAnnotations *)annotation {
    _name.text = annotation.name;
}
```

**Please tell me where i'm wrong?**

Comment: Add a breakpoint to your detailview's viewDidLoad method to check if you're actually loading that view. My guess is, you didn't set the view controller's class in the storyboard and it's calling a generic UIViewController instead of your custom View Controller.

Comment: Yes u r right solution written below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the exception you are sending `setAnnotation:` to an instance of UINavigationController. Since the only place where you use `setAnnotation:` is this line:

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setAnnotation:annotationView.annotation];
```

one can assume that `[segue destinationViewController]` is an instance of UINavigationController. Most likely because your segue presents a ViewController which is embedded in a UINavigationController.

You might be able to access the real target viewController by using the `viewControllers` array of the UINavigationController:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];
ACDetailMapController *viewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0];
[viewController setAnnotation:annotationView.annotation];
```

Comment: @Matthias: I had my code I'm also getting crash, please try to help
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)MapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [MapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CallToProfile" sender:view];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CallToProfile"])
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = sender;
        [segue.destinationViewController setAnnotation:annotationView.annotation];
    }
}